# Menu not working

Tags: java, android

Working with a Xoom Tablet and the menu(options) button on the bottom of the screen does not light up (is not active).

Any suggestions?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection    
    switch (item.getItemId()) {    
    case R.id.about:   
        about();        
        return true;    
    default:        
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    
    }
}
private void about() {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("About");
    alertDialog.setMessage("App v1.0");
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          // here you can add functions
       }
    });
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Are they showing up in the ActionBar instead?

Comment: Just an unrelated hint: If you only want the "OK" button to dispose of the dialog, you don't need that no-op `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` -- just write `alertDialog.setButton("OK", null)`. `AlertDialog` automatically disposes dialogs after button pushes.

Comment: I figured it out..

My target Sdk was:
`android:targetSdkVersion="11"`

Changed to:`android:targetSdkVersion="10"`

Menu button doesn't work on 11 and up. My app is a webapp and I don't think the ActionBar will work in a webapp. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @user899641: "Menu button doesn't work on 11 and up." -- sure it does. It is in the action bar, not the system bar. "My app is a webapp and I don't think the ActionBar will work in a webapp" -- if you are writing Java code, you can have an action bar.

Comment: @CommonsWare My entire app is written in HTML/Javascript. Can I still have an ActionBar?

Comment: @user899641: "My entire app is written in HTML/Javascript." -- then what is the Java code doing in your question?

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, except for that... I just wanted to add an options menu. And I don't know how to implement an ActionBar with HTML, or if it's possible.

Comment: @user899641: You don't add an ActionBar with HTML. You don't do much of anything with HTML in a regular Android app. If you want to write an HTML-based Android app, just use PhoneGap and follow their design guidelines, which (last I checked) tended to not use native menus of any form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out..

My target and min Sdk was:

`android:targetSdkVersion="11"`

`android:minSdkVersion="11"`

Changed to:

`android:targetSdkVersion="11"`

`android:minSdkVersion="10"`

Menu button doesn't work on 11 and up.

Answer (score 1):

The menu key shown on the system bar in Android 3.0+ is a compatibility feature for running older apps. Setting targetSdkVersion="10" means you are not developing an app that targets Android 3.0+ and the system will adjust compatibility behavior for your app accordingly.

If you are truly writing an app to run on Android 3.0+ tablets you will not have a menu key on the system bar. Forget about it. Put it out of your mind. :) Abusing compatibility features in this way explicitly breaks Android UI design guidelines. The action bar will present your activity's options menu if present. If you do not have an action bar in your activity you should present options using some other on-screen affordance.